# How to set AntTweakBar to be on top of OpenGL 3 content (using GLFW)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl-3, glfw

I am using GLFW to display some OpenGL content in MSVS 2010. I want to use AntTweakBar to modify some directive variables (speed rotation, object size, ...) and I want this bar to be above the OpenGL content (not behind as you can see in the picture).

I read the manual, followed the examples but I cant figure out how to set this.

Examples use old deprecated fixed pipeline however I use dynamic pipline so i guess that might be problem.

Picture: (i donr have enough rep to post it directly)
http://s9.postimg.org/43aa3pt0v/cube.png

Code:

```
TwInit(TW_OPENGL_CORE, NULL);

int width=0;
int height=0;
glfwGetWindowSize(&width,&height);

TwWindowSize(width, height);

TwBar * BuildingGUI = TwNewBar("Window settings");
TwSetParam(BuildingGUI, NULL, "refresh", TW_PARAM_CSTRING, 1, "0.1");
TwDefine(" 'Window settings' alwaystop=true ")
TwAddVarRW(BuildingGUI, "Movement Speed"  , TW_TYPE_FLOAT, &speed, "step=0.1");
```

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and placed the TwDraw(); function just before glfwSwapBuffers inside the draw function.